# Regex remove some text a a hyper link

Tags: c#, regex

```
click <a href="javascript:validate('http://www.google.com');">here</a> to open google.com
```

I need to replace the above sentence to the following:

```
click <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a> to open google.com
```

Please help me with the regular expression to do this in C#

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack:  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Austin should submit this as an answer, as using the DOM may be a preferred solution to Regex parsing for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Regex regex = new Regex ("href\=\".+?'(.+)'", 
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
```

then youll need to extract Group #1 :

```
matches .Groups[1]
```

and this is your new value to assign.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

The Regex:

```
(?<=href\=")(javascript:validate\('(?<URL>[^"']*)'\);)
```

The Code:

```
string url = "click <a href=\"javascript:validate('http://www.google.com');\">here</a> to open google.com";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=href\\=\")javascript:validate\\('(?<URL>[^\"']*)'\\);");
string output = regex.Replace(url, "${URL}");
```

The Output:

```
click <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a> to open google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

No Regex needed:

```
var s = 
    inputString.Replace(
        "javascript:validate('http://www.google.com');",
        "http://www.google.com" );
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to use regex because the url (http://www.google.com) will not be the same every time.  I doubt he would ask about how to do this with regex if it were possible for him to just use `Replace`.

Comment: Yes, I do _think_ that too, but from what he asked I cannot derive it, so I tried to answer just what he asked.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the HTML as Austin suggested is a much more efficient way of doing this, but if you absolutely must use REGEX try something like this ([referenced from MSDN System.Text.RegularExpressions Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MyClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = @"<a href=\"[^\(]*\('([^']+)'\);\">";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string sInput = "click <a href=\"javascript:validate('http://www.google.com');\">here</a> to open google.com";

        MyClass c = new MyClass();

        // Assign the replace method to the MatchEvaluator delegate.
        MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(c.ReplaceCC);

        // Write out the original string.
        Console.WriteLine(sInput);

        // Replace matched characters using the delegate method.
        sInput = r.Replace(sInput, myEvaluator);

        // Write out the modified string.
        Console.WriteLine(sInput);
    }

    // Replace each Regex cc match
    public string ReplaceCC(Match m)
    {
        return "click <a href=\"" + m.Group[0] + "\">";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

This is the preferred method for parsing HTML.